# Resize Image Div with respect text div next to it

Tags: html, css

I have design which needs and image and text align next to each other in div(using col-md-6)i need height image to be resize wrt text div.on tablet and mobile it has be 12 column layout

Here is my html code

```
<div class="row fixed-height">
                  <div class="col-md-6 full-screen-col img-head"></div><!--col for imag row ends here-->
                  <div class="col-md-6 cont-bg full-screen-col">
                    <div class="description_container">
                        <h1>JOIN OUR TEAM</h1>
                        <p>We except a lot from our team members, and we give a lot in return- like ongoing training, professional growth 
                        opportunities and competitive benefits. if Gaspar's sounds like your kind of workplace, we'd love to hear from you</p>
                    </div>
                  </div><!--container for text details-->
              </div><!--row fors slide container -->
```

Here is css used.

```
.fixed-height{
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.img-head{
    background-image: url(../images/Gaspars-Construction-Employee-Photo-1024x683.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Little help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: use sm for mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: 
HTML

```
<div class="row fixed-height">
     <div class="col-md-6 full-screen-col img-head">
          <img src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/308/308116-bigthumbnail.jpg"/>
     </div><!--col for imag row ends here-->
     <div class="col-md-6 cont-bg full-screen-col">
          <div class="description_container">
               <h1>JOIN OUR TEAM</h1>
               <p>We except a lot from our team members, and we give a lot in return- like ongoing training, professional growth opportunities and competitive benefits. if Gaspar's sounds like your kind of workplace, we'd love to hear from you</p>
          </div>
     </div><!--container for text details-->
</div><!--row fors slide container -->
```

CSS

```
.img-head{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: when you resize it mobile and tablet image is not visible

Comment: similar to col-md-6 there is one class name for mobile in bootstrap. check it out and use it should work.

Comment: when i add sm-12 image is not visible

Answer (score 0):

Add this,

```
<div class="row fixed-height">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 full-screen-col img-head"></div><!--col for imag row ends here-->
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 cont-bg full-screen-col">
                <div class="description_container">
                    <h1>JOIN OUR TEAM</h1>
                    <p>We except a lot from our team members, and we give a lot in return- like ongoing training, professional growth 
                    opportunities and competitive benefits. if Gaspar's sounds like your kind of workplace, we'd love to hear from you</p>
                </div>
              </div><!--container for text details-->
          </div><!--row fors slide container -->
```